# Longtable caption is not showing

Tags: captions, longtable

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.07\linewidth} p{0.6\linewidth}}
\caption{Online reputation papers organised by the ASC Framework.}
\label{tab:table4}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Paper} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ASC\_Framework} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{Findings/Contribution} \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  Antecedents &
  Strategies &
  Consequences &
 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Paper} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{ASC\_Framework} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{Findings/Contribution} \\ \cline{2-4}
 &
  Antecedents &
  Strategies &
  Consequences &
 \\ \hline
\endhead
...
...
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: please post an example that shows the problem, not just  fragment but `p{0.07\linewidth}`  do you really intend such narrow columns? (or at least I assume this is narrow, you have given no indication of how big `\linewidth` is)

Comment: It worked fine for me, except that most of the p columns were way too narrow.  You can add hyphens manually.

Comment: Do you mean the title in bold does not show up?